# How to copy values from one sheet and paste them into another using Google Sheets Macros?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a Google Sheets Macros without having a lot of knowledge about syntax.

What I want to do is the following:

I want to copy the values which are matching in a source matrix into another table. However, I don't know how to write that as a Macros.

I've written the following code:

```
function CalcularCruces() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Cruces Activo-Amenazas");
  var destinationSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Análisis de Riesgos");

  /** Total number of left column values from source table **/
  const maxAmenazas = 29;

  for(var i = 0; i < maxAmenazas; i++) {
    /** Now I need to get the column and row values which are matching with the checkbox 
        and paste them into another table **/
  }

};
```

Here is an example of the input table and how the output table should look like after executing the macros.

Input Table Sheet[image]
Output Table Sheet[image]

**Edit:**

I need the data to be written next to this static columns:

Actual Output
[image: Actual Output]

Desired Output
[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Try  learning arrays [here](https://w3schools.com/js). You can use sheet.getDataRange().getValues() to get a array and modify it accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

- Retrieve the data from the source sheet via [getDataRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) and [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()).
- For each row in this data (excluding the headers row, that has been retrieved and removed from the array with [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)), check which columns have the checkbox marked.
- If the corresponding checkbox is marked, write the corresponding values to the destination sheet with [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)).

It could be something like this:

```js
function CalcularCruces() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Cruces Activo-Amenazas");
  var destinationSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Análisis de Riesgos");
  destinationSheet.getRange("A2:B").clearContent();
  var values = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues(); // 2D array with all data from source sheet
  var headers = values.shift(); // Remove and retrieve the headers row
  for (var i = 1; i < values[0].length; i++) { // Iterate through each column
    for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) { // Iterate through each row
      var activo = values[j][0]; // Activo corresponding to this row
      if (values[j][i]) { // Check that checkbox is marked
        // Get the row index to write to (first row in which column A and B are empty):
        var firstRow = 2;
        var firstCol = 1;
        var numRows = destinationSheet.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1;
        var numCols = 2;
        var firstEmptyRow = destinationSheet.getRange(firstRow, firstCol, numRows, numCols).getValues().filter(function(row) {
          return row[0] !== "" && row[1] !== "";
        }).length + firstRow;
        // Write data to first row with empty columns A/B:
        destinationSheet.getRange(firstEmptyRow, firstCol, 1, numCols).setValues([[headers[i], activo]]);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

#### Notes:

- All data is added to the target sheet every time the script is run, and this can lead to duplicate rows. If you want to avoid that, you can use [clearContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent) at the beginning of your script, after declaring `destinationSheet`, to remove all previous content (headers excluded):

```js
destinationSheet.getRange("A2:B").clearContent();
```

- In this sample, the number of `amenazas` is not hard-coded, but it dynamically gets the number of rows in the source sheet with `getValues().length`. I'm assuming that's a good outcome for you.
- **UPDATE**: Since you have other columns in your target sheet, you cannot use `appendRow` but `setValues`. First, you have to find the index of the first row in which columns A and B are empty. This is achieved with filtering the array of values in columns A-B and filtering out the elements in which the two values are empty (with [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)).

#### Reference:

- [Sheet.getDataRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)
- [Range.getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [Array.prototype.shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)
- [Sheet.appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))
- [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Range.clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent)

Comment: Ok, it's working and getting the desired items, however, in the ouput sheets I've some extra static columns that should appear in the same row as the items, but the script is appending the 2 items in a new line instead of the 2 first columns of the first row. Hope I explain well, I cannot paste an image here, editing main post.

Comment: @JavierAlonsoDelgado I updated my answer based on your comment. Let me know if that works for you.